# Azure Mobile Service OAuth in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin, oauth, xamarin.ios

I am Creating a Xamarin Native project for iOS and Android. I am using Microsoft Azure as my backend and azure OAuth for authentication. I added Microsoft Azure Mobile Client to both iOs and Android project.

In Xamarin.Android Project, I did authentication with azure with following code:

```
MobileServiceClient  client = new MobileServiceClient("my-azure-app-url");
var user = client.LoginAsync(this, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory);
```

Above Code works fine and i am able to do authentication.

Same i tried in Xamain.iOS also but i can to know the initialisation of MobileServiceClient is different in iOs.

```
MobileServiceClient  client = new MobileServiceClient("my-azure-app-url", HttpMessageHandler);
```

I am not able to find what is this HttpMessageHandler. Can any one help me with the solution

Answer (score 0):

An [HTTP message handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler(v=vs.118).aspx) is responsible for the actual communication going on between client and server.

There is a default (managed) implementation that will be used if you do not specify a handler. But you could go ahead and tell `HttpClient` to use a native one on iOS (as well as Android). You could use [ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient) or use [Xamarin Studio to configure](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_9/xamarin.ios_9.8/#NSUrlSessionHandler) the use of `NSUrlSession` (on iOS). I highly recommend to use a native handler to support IPv6 environments and to increase performance.

In your case, you would either omit the handler parameter or use a `new System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler()`.

If you add ModernHttpClient into your app, you would pass in a `new NativeMessageHandler()`.

An example can be found in my [repo](https://github.com/Krumelur/AzureSyncDemo/blob/ec8e83d420238fe5c2f6e655f0cbd6577c5a1222/Forms/TodoItemManager.cs#L42) about Azure offline syncing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue setting up Azure Mobile Service with my Xamarin project. I managed to succeed in establishing the Mobile Service Client after numerous updates and removals of the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client package(s).

I am using the exact same initialization on both the .Droid and the .iOS project:

```
public static MobileServiceClient mobileservice = new MobileServiceClient("my-azure-app-url");
```

Packages attached to both the .Droid and the .iOS project:

- Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client (ver 2.0.1)
- Microsoft.Bcl (ver 1.1.10)
- Microsoft.Bcl.Build (ver 1.0.21)
- Microsoft.Net.Http (ver 2.2.29)

As far as I understood, it all came down to an incompatibility between some packages. I could definitely not get the Azure Mobile Service from the Component store to work. If this is what you've used, try installing the packages manually. In the end, that's what worked for me.